# How to automatically set a cell in mySQL if the time is within a current range

Tags: mysql

is there a functionality in mySQL that automatically updates a value of a cell if the current time is within the range of another cell ( that is time Data type)

Assuming the table

```
id      startTime       endTime        state
----------------------------------------------
1       13:00:00        15:00:00       3
2       12:00:00        16:00:00       6
```

I would like the state to change to 0 if the current time (machine local time) is within the start and end time? Is this possible in mySQL or do i have to run and external script?

if this is possible how would i be able to do it ? Thank you

Comment: You would need to run the script setting up some time intervals between execution. What you need is an SQL UPDATE statement, but then you need to send it to the database and also have something to schedule the script.

Comment: i am new to mySQL so forgive me, but i have read that there is a thing called a mySQL scheduler can it be achieved that way?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there isn't a function that performed your request. But you can implement a query to do this. You can retrieved current time with command:

```
select now();
```

So you can check if the result is in the range

Comment: i have read that there is a thing called a mySQL scheduler can it be achieved that way?

Comment: Yes, with the scheduled event you can create a "temporary event", but you need to insert the logic in the event_body. You can find more: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/

Comment: if the answer has helped you check the post so that others can use it too. Thanks